# SAXParser fails when responce contains Hindi or other special characters

Tags: android, saxparser

I am using SAX parser to parse a XML response but it throws an exception.

`ExpatParser$ParseException : (not well formed) invalid token`

Is there any solution?

Here is my code:

```
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();  
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");
    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(MyRequestURL);  

    DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient(params); 

    postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    ResponseHandler <String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();  
    String response=hc.execute(postMethodURL,res); 


    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = 
        new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes("UTF8"));

    /* SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

    /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

    /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/ 
    MyHandler objHandler = new MyHandler();
    xr.setContentHandler(objHandler);      

   InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(byteArrayInputStream);
   inputSource.setEncoding("UTF-8");

   /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */

   xr.parse(inputSource);

   /* Parsing has finished. */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Answer**

The ampersand character (**&**) and the left angle bracket (**<**) MUST NOT appear in your xml output in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a **CDATA** section. If they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings " **&** " and "**<** " respectively.

The right angle bracket (**>**) may be represented using the string " **&gt**; ", and MUST, for compatibility, be escaped using either " **&gt**; " or a character reference when it appears in the string " **]]>** " in content, when that string is not marking the end of a **CDATA** section.

Please check your xml seems that it comes the these special characters(**&,<,>**)

**After discussion with Vaibhav Jani**

Here is the sample xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<first_screen>
   <first_screen_object id="1">
      <name><![CDATA[मानक हिन्दी]]></name>
      <desc><![CDATA[मानक हिन्दीमानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी  मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी]]></desc>
       </first_screen_object>

       <first_screen_object id="2">
      <name><![CDATA[मानक हिन्दी]]></name>
      <desc><![CDATA[मानक हिन्दीमानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी  मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी]]></desc>
         </first_screen_object>


       <first_screen_object id="3">
      <name><![CDATA[मानक हिन्दी]]></name>
      <desc><![CDATA[मानक हिन्दीमानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी  मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी]]></desc>
        </first_screen_object>

       </first_screen>
```

And this the SAX parser for the sample XML

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.sax.Element;
import android.sax.EndTextElementListener;
import android.sax.RootElement;
import android.util.Xml;

public class HindiParser {

    // Constructor
    public HindiParser() {

    }

    public static InputStream getInputStreamFromUrl(String url) {
        InputStream content = null;
        try {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // Execute HTTP Get Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            content = response.getEntity().getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle the exception !
        }
        return content;
    }

    /*
     * <?xml version="1.0"?> <first_screen> <first_screen_object id="1">
     * <name><![CDATA[मानक हिन्दी]]></name> <desc><![CDATA[मानक हिन्दीमानक
     * हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक
     * हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी]]></desc>
     * </first_screen_object>
     * 
     * <first_screen_object id="2"> <name><![CDATA[मानक हिन्दी]]></name>
     * <desc><![CDATA[मानक हिन्दीमानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी
     * मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक
     * हिन्दी]]></desc> </first_screen_object> </first_screen_object>
     * 
     * 
     * <first_screen_object id="3"> <name><![CDATA[मानक हिन्दी]]></name>
     * <desc><![CDATA[मानक हिन्दीमानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी
     * मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक हिन्दी मानक
     * हिन्दी]]></desc> </first_screen_object>
     * 
     * </first_screen>
     */

    public void parse() {
        try {
            RootElement root = new RootElement("first_screen");
            Element firstScreenElemnet = root.getChild("first_screen_object");
            firstScreenElemnet.getChild("name").setEndTextElementListener(
                    new EndTextElementListener() {
                        public void end(String body) {
                            System.out.println("Name is " + body);
                        }
                    });
            firstScreenElemnet.getChild("desc").setEndTextElementListener(
                    new EndTextElementListener() {
                        public void end(String body) {
                            System.out.println("Description  is " + body);
                        }
                    });

            try {
                Xml.parse(
                        getInputStreamFromUrl("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=M6zrbJ0W"),
                        Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are the xml nodes are in English or in Hindi?

Comment: English but contains stuff of other language

Comment: Try to set node value with CDATA

Comment: Will it possible for you to post the demo xml ?

Comment: @Tanmay Mandal The special characters are not displayed while i am trying to add demo xml in question please try to make your self with editor that support such characters(any non ascii characters)

Comment: Xml file->http://pastebin.com/M6zrbJ0W ;;java->>http://pastebin.com/waVe4scG  ;;; and output-->http://pastebin.com/s3bLMfka ...hope this will help you

Comment: I have used `SaxParser` in the example...Works fine...So now what is the problem of yours?

Comment: Please edit answer add proper links for answer to be helpful to others also

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure that it will solve your problem but I'd set the charset on the `InputSource` using its `setEncoding()` method.

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(byteArrayInputStream);
inputSource.setEncoding("UTF-8");

xr.parse(inputSource);
```

Comment: Still problem stayed as it is

Comment: This may have not been marked as the answer but it sure helped me, thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

Try with [android.util.Xml.parse()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Xml.html#parse%28java.io.InputStream,%20android.util.Xml.Encoding,%20org.xml.sax.ContentHandler%29)
First argument InputStream => HttpResponse.getEntity().getContent()
Second argument Xml.Encoding => Xml.Encoding.UTF_8
Last argument ContentHandler => your handler

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the problem:

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(is);
inputSource.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: How can it possibly help to set the encoding to ISO-8859-1? The XML is in UTF-8 and contains Hindi characters. Besides, what is `is` supposed to be in this code?

Comment: not sure why, but somehow setting it tot his helped for me...why?

Answer (score 0):

what encoding are you using?

if you are using ISO-8859-1, try using UTF-8

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: if your document is using UTF-8 encoding, then try response.getBytes("UTF8"). Also, when generating your response, set the response contentType to UTF-8. It should be UTF all the way through.